# Where can I find information about the 16:8 diet?

Tags: diet, weight-loss

It was recommended by my doctor that I lose weight, and he suggested I research the 16:8 diet, which is a fasting diet.

I have found a ton of web sites on the internets, but most of them feel wonky or they only talk about the time.  What I'm trying to figure out is the calorie intake for the 8 hour period?  Is it your standard 2000? 1200?  2000 seems like a lot of calories, a 1200 (600 per meal) seems acceptable but I don't want to starve myself.

I am doing this for weight loss.

Comment: You are probably looking for books about this topic or similar, I suppose?

Comment: I can't post this as an answer, since I don't know this diet and can't explain its plan. But for any weight loss, you generally do not want to go below 1200 kcal/day as a female (1500 as a male) without a doctor's close guidance.  And it's important to focus on balancing your diet with nutrient-dense foods.  But I have to state that I question the sustainability of weight loss from a diet requiring you to do something dramatically different from  when you reach your target weight.  I am a proponent of paradigm-shift diets like the Full Plate Diet or the principles in How Not to Die.

Comment: I have no stake in those books, I like them for their evidence base.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma a book would be great.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Thank you for your comments